# show the Div and hide other Div when 'show more' link related to that company is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

i have 2 divs inside foreach loop .first div has information about a company but shortened form and in second div has full form of information about a company . i want to hide first div and show second div when 'show more ' link of that  company has  clicked .in my code when i click 'show more ' link and it shows  all company not only the company which i clicked .

```
<?php   
  $X         = 0;
  foreach($companyRows as $row){ ?>
  <div class="first" >
        echo "a company information shortend form"
      </div>
      <div class="second" style="display:none">
       echo "a company information full form"
       </div>
       <a class="show_details"> show more</a>                               
  <?php $X++;
  } ?>
```

and here is jQuery .  i am new in  jquery and php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".show_details").click(function(){
            $(".second").show();
            $(".first").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

and want to change show more link to show less.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a parent `<div>` in your loop... so that all this html stay inside a parent div.. this way we can use [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)..

```
<?php   
  $X         = 0;
   foreach($companyRows as $row){ ?>
   <div class="parentDiv"> //***here****
    <div class="first" >
      echo "a company information shortend form"
    </div>
     <div class="second" style="display:none">
       echo "a company information full form"
     </div>
     <a class="show_details show_more"> show more</a>    //updated 
 </div>                           
<?php $X++;
} ?>
```

**JQUERY**
****UPDATED****

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".show_details").click(function(){
        var $this=$(this);
        var $parent= $this.parent();
        if($this.hasClass('show_more')){
            $this.removeClass('show_more').addClass('show_less');

            $parent.find('.second').show(); //find parent div and div with second class inside that parent div
           $parent.find(".first").hide();
           $this.html('show Less');  // $(this).text('show Less');
        }else if($this.hasClass('show_less')){
            $this.removeClass('show_less').addClass('show_more');

            $parent.find('.second').hide(); //find parent div and div with second class inside that parent div
           $parent.find(".first").show();
           $this.html('show More');  // $(this).text('show Less'); 
        } 
    });
});
```

[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).. to replace the text inside the clicked link or u can use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: thanx man .... nice . but what if i want to hide second div and show first div again .have you checked that website which i sent to you .

Answer (score 0):

try this if you don't want to add a further DIV-element

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".show_details").click(function(){
            $(this).prev().show();
            $(this).prev().prev().hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

CHange your code this way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".show_details").click(function(){
            var $parent=$(this).parent();
            $parent.find(".second").show();
            $parent.(".first").hide();
        });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".show_details").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".first").hide(100, function() {
            $(this).parent().find('.second').show(100);
            $(this).html(" show less").addClass("hide_details").removeClass("show_details");
        });
    });
});
```